# How to add folds to clothes?

Tags: sculpting

Can somebody please tell me how to add folds to clothes. Just like it’s shown on[image] the picture

Comment: If you're talking about the natural folds, you need a high-poly version of your cloth, then you can use the Crease brush in Sculpt mode (and press Ctrl to invert its effect), then bake the normals? If you're talking about all the seams (hems) we see, select some edge loops, bevel and extrude, or simply use some black lines on a bump map to fake them?

Comment: Have a look at cloth brush. There are many tutorials online. Like this one for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UskiTAah1-w